# CASE WHEN statement producing duplicates?

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, case, common-table-expression

The code below is to output a final table - the issue is the final rows count in the final output table (23,000) is greater than the row count in the #ALL_TXNS table(5,000). #ALL_TXNS table determines the number of rows that will be pulled out as this data is transactional data and only where there is a row in #ALL_TXNS should there be any in final output select statement so the final output should have 5000 rows. Is it the CASE WHEN statement deriving the In_Memory_Donation field in final output that is causing the duplicates? As i understand it CASE WHEN shouldnt create duplicates so perhaps i am using the wrong JOIN? I am using SSMS v18.7

````sql
USE [DB1]
 
       ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /* 6.Select where in memory donation */
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    SELECT *  
    INTO #InMem_txns
    FROM #ALL_TXNS as T 
    where T.notes NOT LIKE '%PROVISIONAL BATCH%'
    
    
     SELECT
     T.ID
     ,CASE
        WHEN IMT.notes not like '%provisional batch%'           THEN 'Y'
        ELSE 'N'
    END                             AS 'In_Memory_Donation'
    INTO #temp_AllData
    FROM #ALL_TXNS AS T 
    LEFT JOIN #temp_contacts AS TC                  ON TC.contact_number = T.contact_number
    LEFT JOIN #InMem_txns AS IMT                    ON IMT.contact_number = T.contact_number
    ORDER BY 1
    
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /* FINAL OUTPUT */
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    SELECT
        In_Memory_Donation         AS 'IN MEMORY DONATION'
    FROM #temp_AllData
    ORDER BY ID ASC```
````

Comment: `CASE` **expression**. T-SQL does not support `Case` (`Switch`) statements.

Comment: Also, I'm sure not *all* of that code is required; that the time to provide a [mre] (emphasis on the **minimal**).

Comment: Also, just in case you don't understand the implications of all the `NOLOCK` hints you have: [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: @Larnu thanks great article about NOLOCK. Will re-evaluate

Comment: @Larnu other CASE expression in code appear to be working as expected. What am I missing?

Comment: `CASE` expressions don't create rows, so can't create duplicates. What ever is causing the "problem" has nothing to do with your `CASE` expressions. Again, we need a [mre] here.

Comment: Code changed as adviced; will that do?

Comment: I can't run that SQL, nor do you tell us what's wrong with it or what you expect. You need to provide a [mre] with expected result/behaviour.

Comment: unfortunately i cant produce a minimal version of the the code and still explain what the issue is. Thank you for your time